# Why does this regex expression not work?

Tags: regex, perl, bash, grep, echo

```
$ echo '!abcae20' | grep -o -P '(?=.*\d)\w{4,}'
```

This will output *nothing*.

But the following works:

```
$ echo '!abcae20' | grep -o -P '.*?(?=.*\d)\w{4,}'

!abcae20
```

Could anyone give me an explanation?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Interestingly, you can use `\w*` and `\w?` instead of `\w{4,}`, and both of them will produce the expected results. But `\w`, `\w+` and every `\w{k,l}` I tried produce no match.

Answer (score 2):

In your first  expression the lookahead assertion is matching your input as (`greedy`).

Running a debug test on your regular expression displays the following.

```
Matching REx "(?=.*\d)\w{4,}" against "!abcae20"
0 <> <!abcae20>           |  1: IFMATCH[0](8)
0 <> <!abcae20>           |  3: STAR(5)
                                REG_ANY can match 8 times out of 2147483647...
8 <!abcae20> <>           |  5: DIGIT(6)
                                failed...
7 <!abcae2> <0>           |  5: DIGIT(6)
8 <!abcae20> <>           |  6: SUCCEED(0)
                                subpattern success...
0 <> <!abcae20>           |  8: CURLY {4,32767}(11)
                                ALNUMU can match 0 times out of 2147483647...
                                failed...
Match failed
```

- Explanation on what caused the match to fail..

  1. <**!abcae20**>

     ```
     The greedy quantifier first matches as much as possible. 
     So the .* here is matching the entire string.
     ```
  2. <`!abcae20`>

     ```
     Then tries to match any numeric character following, 
     but there are no characters left to match.
     ```
  3. <`!abcae2`**0**>

     ```
     So it backtracks making the greedy match, match one less 
     character leaving the  --> 0 <--  at the end unmatched.
     ```
  4. <`!abcae20`>

     ```
     So it backtracks again matching one less leaving it unmatched.
     ```
  5. <**!abcae20**>

     ```
     So it backtracks one more step matching one less again and failing your match.
     ```
- Regular expression explained:

  ```
  (?=             look ahead to see if there is:
   .*             any character except \n (0 or more times)
   \d             digits (0-9)
  )               end of look-ahead
  \w{4,}          word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (at least 4 times)
  ```

Your second expression does match `!` with the preceding non-greedy `.*?` followed by your lookahead assertion which matches `!abcae2`, then backtracks to match your word characters and complete string.

- Regular expression explained:

  ```
  .*?             any character except \n (0 or more times)
   (?=            look ahead to see if there is:
    .*            any character except \n (0 or more times)
    \d            digits (0-9)
   )              end of look-ahead
   \w{4,}         word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (at least 4 times)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
echo '!abcae20' | grep -o -P '.*?(?=.*\d)\w{4,}
```

Because the `.*?` matches the `!`, the `(?=.*\d)` matches `abcae20`, and the `\w{4,}` matches abcae20.

In this one:

```
echo '!abcae20' | grep -o -P '(?=.*\d)\w{4,}'
```

The lookahead matches `!abcae20`, being greedy. However, the `\w{4,}` can't match the `!` so it fails.

Here is the perl regex debug output for the failing one:

```
Matching REx "(?=.*\d)\w{4,}" against "!abcae20"
   0 <> <!abcae20>           |  1:IFMATCH[0](8)
   0 <> <!abcae20>           |  3:  STAR(5)
                                    REG_ANY can match 8 times out of 2147483647...
   8 <!abcae20> <>           |  5:    DIGIT(6)
                                      failed...
   7 <!abcae2> <0>           |  5:    DIGIT(6)
   8 <!abcae20> <>           |  6:    SUCCEED(0)
                                      subpattern success...
   0 <> <!abcae20>           |  8:CURLY {4,32767}(11)
                                  ALNUM can match 0 times out of 2147483647...
                                  failed...
```

Comment: So how do you explain the fact that `(?=.*\d)\w*` outputs `abcae20`?

Comment: The lookahead matches !abcae20, the `\w*` matches nothing

Comment: Why does the `.*?` match `!` and the `.*` in the lookahead not?

Comment: @Kevin, the `.*` in the lookahead matches everything, including the `!`. But starting from the `!`, `\w{4,}` fails.

Comment: @perreal:the lookahead is supposed to be "zero-length" ("Look-around assertions are zero-width patterns which match a specific pattern without including it in $&"). (And try the `\w?` case.)

Comment: @rici, it is because lookahead is zero length is why this is failing. Whatever the lookahead matches should be matched by the following term.

Comment: @perreal: So explain the output when you use `\w?`. It's supposed to be a substring match, not an anchored match. If it fails on the first position, it should try the second one, which is what happens with `\w?`

Comment: I got it, the lookahead doesn't advance the input so the engine goes back to where the lookahead started.  However, as grep only needs to match any subset of the line, why doesn't it backtrack with the `.*` and start from the first `a`?

Comment: @perreal: replace `\w{4,}` with `\w?`. It then finds seven one-character matches.

Comment: @rici, again, the lookahead matches !abcae20, the `\w?` matches nothing so it succeeds. I think it is wrong to start lookahead without a preceding term so it assumes the regex is anchored at the start of string.

Comment: @perreal: that doesn't explain why it finds the match `a`. It couldn't find that with an anchored match. For that matter, if you use `\w*`, it finds the (unanchored) abcae20 (no bang).

Comment: @rici, you don't seem to understand the fact that whatever is matched by the lookahead should be matched by the following term. `\w*` can match `!` but `\w{4,}` can't.

Comment: @perreal: Here's a couple more oddities. `(?=.*\d)a` matches `a`. `(?=.*\d)ab` matches `ab`. `(?=.*\d)[ab]` matches nothing (!). `(?=.*\d)[ab]*` matches `ab`.

Comment: @rici, the success of the match is correct in all cases, the behavior of the `-o` flag is weird. It looks like the engine first tests a match, then prints out all possible matches.

Comment: @perreal: -o prints out successive matches; i.e., it restarts the search at the end of the previous match. At least, that's how it works in non-pcre modes. But I don't get how the match with `a` is correctly `a` and the match with `[ab]` is not. `[ab]` certainly should match `a`, why would it have different output? And `a` does *not* match the `!`, just like `\w{4,}` doesn't, as per your previous comment.

Comment: @rici, you are right, the `a` should fail. It fails in Perl: `anchored "a" at 0 (checking anchored) anchored(MBOL) implicit minlen 1 
Guessing start of match in sv for REx "(?=.*\d)([a])" against "!abcae20"
Found anchored substr "a" at offset 1...`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo '!abcae20' | grep -o -P '(?=.*\d)\w{4,}'
```

In this regex, lookahead `(?=.*\d)` catches `!abcae2` at the beginning of the string itself, hence will try to mach for `\w{4,}` from the starting of the string. But since there is `!` which doesn't match with `\w`, a complete match fails

Probably following regex will clear the things

```
$ echo '!abcae20' | grep -o -P '(?=\w*\d)\w{4,}'
abcae20
```

Here lookahead only catches `abcae2` and match starts from `a` onwards, hence the resultant match `abcae20`

---

```
$ echo '!abcae20' | grep -o -P '.*?(?=.*\d)\w{4,}'
!abcae20
```

In above regex, you allow `!` first to be captured by `.*?`, hence a complete match.

Answer (score 1):

According to `man pcrepattern`:

> If a pattern starts with `.*` or `.{0,}` and the `PCRE_DOTALL` option (equivalent to Perl's `/s`) is set, thus allowing the dot to match new‐lines, the pattern is **implicitly anchored**, because whatever follows will be tried against every character position in the subject string, so there is no point in retrying the overall match at any position after the first.

As the manpage goes on to mention, that optimization cannot be used if the `.*` is inside a parenthesized group used as a back-reference, since in that case there may be a point in retrying the overall match at some later position. The same argument would imply that this optimization is incorrect in the case of zero-length lookaheads, as the pattern in the OP mentions.

It's not clear from the manpage whether the `.*` in the lookahead causes an implicit anchor, but it's certainly possible (although that would be a bug, imho). For whatever reason, adding `(?-s)`, which I think would turn `PCRE_DOTALL` off, does not change the behaviour. However, changing `.*` to something else does. In particular, changing it to `[^\d]*` causes the regex to have the expected output:

```
$ echo '!abcae20' | grep -P -o '(?=[^\d]*\d)\w{4,}'
abcae20
```

It's at least interesting that there are cases where the lookahead assertion works apparently without creating an implicit anchor, which might cast some doubt on the above analysis. But it might just be an interaction with some other optimization. In particular,

```
$ echo '!abcae20' | grep -P -o '(?=.*\d)a'
a
$
```

clearly couldn't work if the pattern were anchored. On the other hand, changing `a` to `[ab]`, which one might think would not alter the match:

```
$ echo '!abcae20' | grep -P -o '(?=.*\d)[ab]'
$
```

(Many thanks to @perreal for an engaging discussion of this question.)

Some of the observations that initially lead me to think that this might be a bug were:

```
$ echo '!abcde20' | grep -P -o '(?=.*\d)\w*'
abcde20
$ echo '!abcde20' | grep -P -o '(?=.*\d)\w+'
$ echo '!abcde20' | grep -P -o '(?=.*\d)\w'
$ echo '!abcde20' | grep -P -o '(?=.*\d)\w?'
a
b
c
d
e
2
0
```

That all looks illogical, but it actually makes sense if the pattern is implicitly anchored. In the first and last case (`\w*` and `\w`), the pattern will match an empty string at the beginning of the input. `grep -o` will then retry the pattern at the next character position, where it succeeds. In the other two cases (`\w+` and `\w`), the anchored pattern would fail, so `grep` will not retry it.

Nonetheless, I stand by my assertion that the implicit anchoring (if that is what is happening) is a bug, since the manpage is quite clear that it is an *optimization* and an optimization should not change behaviour. (Furthermore, it's inconsistent with the `(?=.*\d)a` match.) But it's possible that the bug is in the documentation, since -- according to @perreal -- Perl also rejects these matches, and `pcre`'s goal is to be Perl-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that:

```
(?=.*\d)\w{4,}
```

returns nothing is because of the first part:

```
(?=.*\d)
```

Which matches the entire expression and is a positive look-ahead. Positive look-ahead is a match whose value is not returned. For a better explanation see [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions)